# How come nobody from Japan?

Tags: discussion

What I like here is that people are from all over the world. India, Switzerland, Netherland, France, US, you name it...

But where are people from Japan? We all know how important gardening is for japanese. And how much they would have contributed. What is the reason for their absence?

Comment: I suspect the English language is the main reason.

Comment: And there are few active people, in any case, so we lack some regions.  Questions are much more diverse, but few people are answering.  I just noticed that our top "answerer" has zero questions.

Answer (score 7):

You could ask the same about China which contains nearly 1/4 of the world's population.  Searching for China brings up zero hits.

Yet, if you visit Chinese households they all seem to have houseplants in my experience, but very limited space to grow anything outside.  And many large public internal spaces have large plants and small trees in stressful locations indicating a high degree of knowledge to get them to thrive.

I suspect with its long heritage in gardening all the resources people need can be obtained by word of mouth.  I suspect the same is true for Japan.

Answer (score 3):

That's a good question.

I actually found a few users when I put "Japan" in our search box. They asked questions about their plants in Japan.

People don't have to list their location in their profile, so it's possible there are more and we just don't know it.

We also have a [Japanese Language SE](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/), which I didn't realize until you posted this! You could pop into their chat room and invite them to contribute over here. They might not even know about us. That could increase our user base, and introduce more types of plants for us to learn about.

You'll need to join the site though, or else you won't have enough rep to go to their chat room. Because you have over 200 rep here, you automatically get 100 at every other one of your sites. That's explained [here](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

I hope you find some people!

Answer (score 3):

As Sue says, I have noticed a few questions from Japan, but they are very rare. In fact, questions from Asia are rare. Except for India, I don't recall seeing questions from Asia on a regular basis.

Maybe they use different gardening sites, just like the Russians using [Vkontakt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VK_(social_networking)) instead of [Facebook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook).    .